# ativando background overlay com link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

tudo bom? estou preparando um layout para um blog e preciso fazer um slidershow mais ou menos da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já conseguir fazer tudo beleza via CSS mais estou com um problema! A imagina só ativa quando o mouse passa por cima da div, mais eu preciso que a imagem seja ativada ou melhor fique colorida quando passar o mouse no link da imagem.

Alguém poderia me da essa ajuda?

Segue o meu codigo via BOOTPLY

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/CyYjZEr33h)

Não sei se tem como fazer isso via CSS ou se faz somente via Javascript, até tentei fazer via javascript mais não entendo muito de JS.

Comment: Você deseja que a imagem seja "ativada" **apenas** quando o mouse estiver sobre o link ou também quando passar sobre a imagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ativar somente no `LINK` irá demandar uma grande alteração, dessa forma para evitar que tenha que refazer todo o código ele está ativando quando coloca em cima da `<div class="over-text-feature">` que contém o texto.

Coloquei a `<div class="img-box-feature">` depois da `<div class="over-text-feature">` dessa forma você pode acessar com `.over-text-feature:hover + div.img-box-feature` usar o operado [`+ (Adjacent Sibling Selector)`](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/) no css faz com que você selecione o irmão adjacente do elemento baseado no seu pai.

Neste caso casso específico ele seleciona o *próximo* `div.img-box-feature` que faz parte do mesmo *pai* do `<div class="over-text-feature">`.

Segue exemplo no [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/YGHuklfBhi)

Comment: é exatamente o que eu queria fazer! não conhecia esse operador + no css! Vivendo e aprendendo!

Answer (score 0):

Basta inserir a div `over-text-feature` dentro da div `img-box-feature`fazendo dela sua filha, assim:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 box-um">
  <div class="img-box-feature" style="background-image:url('http://lounge.obviousmag.org/a_boleia_da_ideia/2012/08/gatimonias-ou-maldita-curiosidade.html.jpg?v=20150627141437')">
    <div class="over-text-feature">
      <h1><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos</a></h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```